# Searching 15k address rows via autocomplete, MySQL like or full text search?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, jquery-autocomplete

I have a db table of Australian postcodes and addresses with 15k rows, each row looking like this:

```
pcode   |   suburb      |   state
2048    |   Westgate    |   NSW
2066    |   Belina      |   NSW
```

Triggered an input field with jQuery autocomplete, I split up the user input and build a LIKE query, searching on the suburb and postcode fields.

This does the trick:

```
SELECT address_id as id, CONCAT(suburb,' ',postcode) as value FROM address WHERE address_id != ''"; 

foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
{
      $query .= " AND (postcode like '".$keyword."%' OR suburb like '%".$keyword."%')";
}
```

I have no indexes on any columns at present (aside from primary key). Would I be better to use some sort of full text index and change the search? or given the amount of data (not huge), is what I'm doing efficient enough

Comment: I think that 15k rows is nothing. I think that it can work even without index

Comment: 15K rows is more overwhelming to the user than to the DB.  How are you handling that? Do they have to put in the state first and then 3+ characters before auto-complete? What's the longest list the user might face?

Comment: I'm putting a limit 25 on the query. Search kicks in after any 3 chars are typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient type of indexes are with numerical column indexes. as others suggested, 15k is not a big set of records , but in terms of user experience, when you type a single character, there can be large number of records thus making it a usability nightmare.

suggestion -   use a LIMIT clause in your sql so that you can limit your resultset to a manageable size.. lets say 15 records at a time..

Comment: This is not necessarily so. Reasonably-sized text (non-numerical) indices work just fine: in the end it's all just data stored in various b-trees and whatnot. Now, things get a little more complicated when talking about all the different nuances of various *update* scenarios and page reads and ... but an index is an index. (The question is then: *is* the index used [correctly] by the query planner?)

Answer (score 1):

When using index, you're not able to use `LIKE '%something%'`, so if you need to be able to search in the middle of string, don't bother to use index at all

> This is the reason MATCH command allows prefixed wildcards but not postfixed wilcards. Since single words are indexed, a postfix wildcard is impossible to manage in the usual way index does. You can't retrieve '*nited states' instantly from index because left characters are the most important part of index.

[source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#c8632)